# ng-repeat с фильтром не пускает пустой массив

Tags: angularjs

Пытаюсь сделать мульти-фильтр для ng-repeat. Но когда мой фильтр отдает пустой массив, выскакивает это:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: task in tasks | multipleFilter:filter, Duplicate key: undefined:undefined, Duplicate value: undefined
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks | multipleFilter:filter">
```

Фильтр:

```
function multipleFilter() {
  return function(input, filters) {
    console.log(arguments);
    for (var index in input) {
      var current = input[index];
      for (var filter in filters) {
        console.log("filter is", filter, filters[filter]);
        if (filters[filter] == "all") continue;
        if (Array.isArray(filters[filter]) && filters[filter].indexOf(current[filter]) === -1) delete input[index];
      }
    }
    console.log("Outer input: ", input);
    return input;
  }
}
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tspb6exc/) (простите за бардак в HTML). Нужно сделать, чтобы фильтры работали.

Comment: убери все лишнее из примера, и добавь в вопрос пример входных данных для фильтра и пример выходных.

Comment: @Grundy, там, кроме HTML ничего лишнего нет, да и тут больше JS важен, ежели HTML.

Comment: в примере сейчас слишком много разметки и кода, плюс непонятно что именно и по какому принципу фильтруется.

Comment: @Grundy, сделал код чище, посмотрите https://jsfiddle.net/tspb6exc/1/

Comment: Что происходит в функции select? какая-то непонятная магия с превращением строки в массив. И я до сих пор не вижу описания: как именно фильтр должен работать

Comment: В HTML есть фильтры. При клике на один из фильтров, в функцию select передается ключ, того что нужно фильтровать и его требуемое значение. Затем все сохраняется в объект `$scope.filter`. Потом сам фильтр проверяет входные данные и на выходе отдает отфильтрованный список, который создается с помощью `$scope.filter`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42940/discussion-between-grundy-and-blits).

Comment: Ответил в чате.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема - неверный фильтр.

`delete input[index]` удаляет элемент, но не изменяет свойство `length` у массива и не сдвигает оставшиеся индексы. В итоге получается массив вида

```
[a,b,undefined,undefined]
```

и так как присутствуют два одинаковых объекта *undefined* - падает `ng-repeat`.

Быстрым обходным путем может быть использование `track by $index` - в этом случае уникальность будет определяться по номеру элемента, но при этому выводиться будут даже пустые элементы.

Правильнее всего будет исправить сам фильтр.

Сейчас при использовании `delete` либо `splice` - изменяется исходная коллекция. Для исправления можно воспользоваться функцией [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), которая возвращает *новый* массив не меняя исходный.

Comment: Если я использую `track by`, то фильтр вообще не обновляется. Как правильно удалить элемент из фильтра?

Comment: Хмм, ну я использовал `Array.prototype.splice`, исключение пропало, но на входе и выходе я получаю пустой массив.

Comment: @blits, в данном случае очевидно проблема в фильтре

Comment: А конкретнее? Я незнаю, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Я понял, в чем проблема. То значение, которое я отдаю в фильтре записывается в `$scope.tasks`. Но как сделать, чтобы оно туда не записывалось?

Comment: @blits, вообще не понял про `$scope.task`

Comment: $scope.tasks - и есть входные данные, которые я получаю от сервера. Посмотрите комментарий в самом вопросе.